# Need to move script to footer in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have installed a plugin to wp site.Now when i view-source of site, plugin js script show on middle of html.
And have a jquery js link on footer of html. 
plugin not working if jquery link have after plugin scripts.

So how can i move plugin scripts to under jquery link.

Thank you

Comment: you have to write this message to the plugin developer

Comment: what is the plugin name